# A button's title does not show up

Tags: html

I have been making a to do list and i have stumbled upon a problem. There is a button to add to list but it is an empty green square.

I tried to make a button that adds to a list. It should say add to list. Instead it is an empty square. How can i solve it?
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>To-Do list</title>
        <style>
            input[type="button"] {
                background-color: green;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function addToList() {
                var newItem = document.createElement("div");
                newItem.innerHTML = document.getElementById("box").value;
                document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newItem);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <p>To-do list</p>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" id="box" value="enter something">
        <br/>
        <input type="button" vaule="Add to list"
            onclick="addToList();"/>
        <br/>
        <div id="list"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's a typo. `vaule` property should be `value`.

Comment: Ah thanks. I did not see that.

Comment: You are inconsistent with your usage of the closing slash on some tags but note that the [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-br-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Comment: @YurkoFlisk Sorry!!!,I apologize for not seeing your comment with the answer before I posted mine. Please forgive me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="button" vaule="Add to list"
```

this should be:

```
    <input type="button" value="Add to list"
```